# How to elegantly mock a class using pytest fixtures?

Tags: python, pytest, fixtures

Let's say I have a `fixture` to mock a class using `monkeypatch`.

```
# conftest.py
@pytest.fixture
def mock_dummyclass(monkeypatch):
    def mock_function():
        return None
 
    monkeypatch.setattr(dummypackage, "dummyclass", mock_function)
```

Now, I have to use this fixture in my test so that this class is mocked.

```
#test_dummy.py
@pytest.mark.usefixtures("mock_dummyclass")
class TestManyDummyMethods:
    def test_dummy_one():
        import dummypackage  # Flag A
    def test_dummy_two():
        import dummypackage  # Flag B
    ...
    def test_dummy_n():
        import dummypackage  # Flag N
```

As you can see in the flagged lines, that I'll have to import this module `dummypackage` inside every function to ensure that the fixture is applied before the module is imported (otherwise the fixture would not be effective).

Importing `dummypackage` inside the class would work but calling `self.dummypackage` inside functions doesn't seem very elegant either.

Is there a more elegant way to achieve this?

Comment: `dummypackage` can be imported on top of `test_dummy.py` and `dummyclass` will be patched successfully. `from dummypackage import dummyclass` won't work, though. What exactly doesn't work so you resort to moving the imports?

Answer (score -1):

<s>Comment: The `monkeypatch` library doesn't seem to be maintained anymore. `unittest.mock` should probably offer all you need.</s>

I would try to avoid a solution that depends on importing the module as part of your test because that would break if it was imported for another reason (e.g. import other functions).

I am using `os` as an example as that exists and makes it reproducible.

How best to patch seem to depend on how you import from another module.

### Example 1: `target_module1.py` (importing the `join` method from `os.path`):

```
from os.path import join

def some_method_using_join():
    return join('parent', 'child')
```

This requires us to patch the `join` method of `target_module1.py`:

`target_module1_test.py`:

```
from unittest.mock import patch, MagicMock

import pytest

from target_module1 import some_method_using_join

@patch('target_module1.join')
def some_test(join_mock: MagicMock):
    some_method_using_join()
```

### Example 2: `target_module2.py` (importing the `os` module):

```
import os

def some_method_using_join():
    return os.path.join('parent', 'child')
```

This allows us to patch the `join` method on `os.path`:

`target_module2_test.py`:

```
from unittest.mock import patch, MagicMock

import pytest

from target_module2 import some_method_using_join

@patch('os.path.join')
def some_test(join_mock: MagicMock):
    some_method_using_join()
```

This assumes that you don't need to patch a class or method that is used at the module level (i.e. while importing).

Comment: I appreciate the response, however this does not answer my question. My issue is regarding mocking entire class, not methods or functions.

Comment: You can mock a class in the same way. Just replace `join` with the name of the class. And of course the module.

Comment: `monkeypatch` is very well maintained, since it's a fixture provided by `pytest`.

Comment: @hoefling fair point, I mistook it for the library with that name. I will amend / remove my comment.

Comment: @de1; for various reasons I would need to use `monkeypatch` fixtures; unittest.mock would not work

Comment: @rrlamichhane you can use patch in pytest fixtures as well. But apologies for not having made that clear: the point of my answer was meant to show the difference in what to patch depending on how the to be patched method or class etc. is imported.